# In R, I have two columns and would like to take the sum if a condition is met

Tags: r

I have am trying to write a script in R where I would take sum of values correspnding to a condition from another column.
Say I have two columns, fakeVector & fakeVector1 of table "total"

```
fakeVector = c('NTC.H3','NTC.F2','NTC.F22','abc123','sample1')
fakeVector1 = c('1','2','3','4','5')
total=rbind(fakeVector, fakeVector1)
```

I want to get the values for fakeVector1 where fakeVector = specific value.
For example, I would like to grab the fakeVector1 value where fakeVector = specific value, for example "NTC.H3"
How would I do that?

Comment: Try `sum(as.numeric(fakeVector1[fakeVector=="NTC.H3"]))`  Note that the `fakeVector1` is `character` class for unknown reason (assuming that you wanted the `sum`)

Comment: You have two choices: (1) first filter your dataframe to only contain rows that match the condition, then sum the cols into one col or (2) the other way around. Speedwise it will not make much of a difference so choose the one that produces cleaner code.

Comment: `total` is a matrix at the moment, not a data.frame. I think what you're driving at is `total <- data.frame(fakeVector = c('NTC.H3', 'NTC.F2', 'NTC.F22', 'abc123', 'sample1'), fakeVector1 = 1:5)`. Then you can call `aggregate(total$fakeVector1, list(total$fakeVector), sum)` (or the `dplyr` or `data.table` equivalents).

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
sum(as.numeric(total["fakeVector1",][total["fakeVector",]=="NTC.H3"]))
```

Comment: again...like a ninja :)

Comment: @Sotos Sorry, i had no idea that you were also attempting this

Comment: @RichardScriven  You are right, I didn't check it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
total[2,][which(total[1,] == "NTC.H3")]
#[1] "1"

v1 <- c('NTC.H3', 'NTC.F22', 'abc123')
sum(as.numeric(total[2,][which(total[1,] %in% v1)]))
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data set is organized as a `data.frame` and if you want to know the sum of one column for every condition in another column of, you can use the fast `data.table` package.

```
# load library
  library(data.table)

# get your data 
  fakeVector = c('NTC.H3','NTC.F2','NTC.F22','abc123','sample1')
  fakeVector1 = c('1','2','3','4','5')
  total=cbind(fakeVector, fakeVector1)

  total <- as.data.table(total)
  total$fakeVector1 <- as.numeric(total$fakeVector1)

# Solution
  total[, .(mysum = sum(fakeVector1)), by=.(fakeVector)]
```